# Panning with Mouse

Tags: plotting, graphics, manipulate, dynamic

This is related to the question i just asked [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/102859/moving-the-axis-origin-0-0-with-a-mouse/102882#102882) but not the same.

How could i create a manipulate that lets me move the graph to any position i want by clicking and dragging anywhere.  Here is an example of what i want at desmos.com.

[image]

Comment: I think @szabolcs has posted code for this previously

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A version using `Manipulate`:

```
Manipulate[
 Graphics[{}, Axes -> True, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, PlotRange -> pr, 
  GridLines -> Range @@@ Round@pr, GridLinesStyle -> LightGray], 
 {{p, {0, 0}}, Locator, 
  TrackingFunction -> {p = MousePosition[{"Graphics", Graphics}, {0, 0}]; &, 
    If[MousePosition["GraphicsScaled"] ∈ Rectangle[], 
       pr += p - MousePosition[{"Graphics", Graphics}, {0, 0}]]; &, None}, 
  Appearance -> None}, 
 {{pr, {{-5, 5}, {-5, 5}}}, None}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 11):

Again I choose a dynamic module to implement your request. This time I don't use a locator, but take direct control of mouse events.

```
With[{span = 10., viscosity = .01},
  Framed @ 
    DynamicModule[{mouseXY, xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax},
      {xmin, xmax} = {ymin, ymax} = span {-1., 1.}/2.;
      EventHandler[
        Dynamic @ 
          Plot[span Sin[t]/2., {t, xmin, xmax},
          AspectRatio -> Automatic,
          PlotRange -> {{xmin, xmax}, {ymin, ymax}}, 
          GridLines -> {Floor /@ Range[xmin, xmax], Floor /@ Range[ymin, ymax]}],
        {"MouseDown" :> (mouseXY = MousePosition[])},
        {"MouseDragged" :>
          Module[{dx, dy},
            {dx, dy} = viscosity (MousePosition[] - mouseXY);
            mouseXY = MousePosition[];
            xmin -= dx; xmax -= dx;
            ymin += dy; ymax += dy]}]]]
```

[image: plot]

#### Update

Anyone reading this answer should also read Szabolcs' answer too. He makes important simplifications to my code by fixing a coordinate system error I made and then clumsily worked-around.

Comment: I think mouse events are the way to go.  Opens up a whole new can of worms for me.  But I enjoy worms.  Thank you.

Answer (score 11):

This is a direct copy-paste of @m_godberg's code, with a few minor changes to get rid of the `viscosity` parameter and allow the graphics to move precisely as much as the mouse was dragged.

```
With[{span = 10.},
  Framed @ 
    DynamicModule[{mouseXY, xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax},
      {xmin, xmax} = {ymin, ymax} = span {-1., 1.}/2.;
      EventHandler[
        Dynamic @ 
          Plot[span Sin[t]/2., {t, xmin, xmax},
          AspectRatio -> Automatic,
          PlotRange -> {{xmin, xmax}, {ymin, ymax}}, 
          GridLines -> {Floor /@ Range[xmin, xmax], Floor /@ Range[ymin, ymax]}],
        {"MouseDown" :> (mouseXY = MousePosition["Graphics"])},
        {"MouseDragged" :>
          Module[{dx, dy},
            {dx, dy} =  (MousePosition["Graphics"] - mouseXY);           
            xmin -= dx; xmax -= dx;
            ymin -= dy; ymax -= dy]}]]]
```

Comment: Ah, I knew there was something bad about my code needing `viscosity` and having `y` increase from top to bottom. I totally forgot about the `"Graphics"` argument.

Comment: @m_goldberg If you want to add this alternative to your answer, I'll delete mine for the sake of keeping the thread clean :-)

Comment: No, I'll just add a pointer to your answer to mine. This answer has been up-voted and should stand.

Comment: @m_goldberg Well, the truth is that I would not have taken the effort to implement this fully if I didn't have your code as a starting point ...  and I don't care too much about upvotes.

Answer (score 1):

```
  Manipulate[
      Graphics[ 
  AxesOrigin -> a,
  Frame -> True,
  GridLines -> {b = (Range[-10, 10] /. 0 -> {0, Thick}), b},
  PlotRange -> {{a[[1]] - 3, a[[1]] + 3}, 
                {a[[2]] - 3, a[[2]] + 3}}],
 {{a, {0, 0}}, {-5, -5}, {5, 5}, Locator, Appearance -> " "}]
```

Comment: This is almost does it.  However, it has as scaling issue that affects single clicking the mouse.  If you single click the mouse anywhere in your graph it shouldn't move it.  the graph should only move when you drag one point to another point.