# Panning with Mouse + Moving A Curve

Tags: plotting, graphics, manipulate, dynamic

I would like to be able to move any curve (for example f(x)=x, or g(x)=x^2) by mouse dragging the particular curve.

I would like to keep the functionality I have for panning across the screen in the code below.  This uses Manipulate, (provided by @Karsten 7) but other solutions using Dynamic can be found [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/102898/moving-any-point-with-a-mouse)

```
Manipulate[

 Plot[{x, x^2}, {x, -3, 3}, Axes -> True, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, 
  PlotRange -> pr, GridLines -> Range @@@ Round@pr, 
  GridLinesStyle -> LightGray],


 {{p, {0, 0}}, Locator, 
  TrackingFunction -> {p = 
       MousePosition[{"Graphics", Graphics}, {0, 0}]; &, 
    If[MousePosition["GraphicsScaled"] \[Element] Rectangle[], 
       pr += p - MousePosition[{"Graphics", Graphics}, {0, 0}]]; &, 
    None}, Appearance -> None},
 {{pr, {{-5, 5}, {-5, 5}}},
  None}]
```

I'm guessing I would like to put a locator on each curve and then move the curve as long as I am close enough to the locator.  What do you think?

Below is a video of what I want to emulate from desmos.com.

[image]

Comment: The current mechanism works because wherever you click in the plane the closest locator is always the one that controls the plot range. If you introduce more locators into the plane this will not be true any longer. Thus you need two different strategies: one for the curves (this could be achieved with locators as you suggest), and one for the panning (this could be m_goldberg's solution, for example.) You will probably need to use global variables to indicate when locators are activated, so that you can inactivate the panning mechanism.

Comment: This makes sense!  I'm going to take a crack at it again.  I'll post a solution if I can come up with one.  Thank you!

Comment: Do you want to have a dragging point for the curve, as shown in your video, or should clicking anywhere on the curve make it draggable?

Comment: I would rather have a point.  But not important right now.  The nice thing about having a point on the curve is that it opens up more opportunities for functionality like rotating the curve about that point for choosing a second point and moving it to alter the slope of a line.  I want it to have the intuitive usability as demos.com but with some more advanced functionality using Mathematica.

Comment: I have some code you might be interested in.  It's not a proper answer to this question because it doesn't allow for dragging of curves.  But what it does do is to allow *arbitrary* panning, by interactively changing the variable range and `PlotRange`.  So, unlike the other solutions here, you won't hit a wall if you pan too far.  It also, somewhat amusingly, supports "throwing".  I don't have it anywhere at the moment, but if there's interest, I could maybe throw it up on a Github gist or something.

Comment: @JohnFultz  Yes I am interested!.  I would be interested in how you implement throwing.  Thank you!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This isn't a very elegant implementation, but since nobody else has answered so far, I've decided to post it. It is an extension of what I posted in [this previous question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/102898/3066).

```
f1[x_] := x^2
f2[x_] := x + 1

With[{span = 10., δ = .1, f1DragPt = {0., f1[0.]}, f2DragPt = {0., f2[0.]}},
  Framed @
    DynamicModule[{mXY, action, xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax, p1, p2},
      {xmin, xmax} = {ymin, ymax} = span {-1., 1.}/2.;
      p1 = p2 = {0., 0.};
    EventHandler[
      Dynamic @
        Plot[
          {f1[t - p1[[1]]] + p1[[2]], f2[t - p2[[1]]] + p2[[2]]}, 
          {t, xmin, xmax}, 
          AspectRatio -> Automatic, 
          PlotRange -> {{xmin, xmax}, {ymin, ymax}},
          GridLines ->
            {Floor /@ Range[xmin, xmax], Floor /@ Range[ymin, ymax]}],
      {"MouseDown" :>
        (mXY = MousePosition["Graphics"];
         Which[
           Abs[f1[mXY[[1]] - p1[[1]]] + p1[[2]] - mXY[[2]]] < δ, action = "moveF1",
           Abs[f2[mXY[[1]] - p2[[1]]] + p2[[2]] - mXY[[2]]] < δ, action = "moveF2",
           True, action = "pan"])},
      {"MouseDragged" :>
        Module[{xy, dx, dy},
          xy = MousePosition["Graphics"];
          Switch[action,
            "pan", 
              {dx, dy} = xy - mXY; xmin -= dx; xmax -= dx; ymin -= dy; ymax -= dy,
            "moveF1", p1 = xy - f1DragPt,
            "moveF2", p2 = xy - f2DragPt]]}]]]
```

Initial plot

[image: initial]

Plot after some panning and curve dragging.

[image: plot]

To select a curve for moving, click anywhere along the curve. However, dragging will always be with the mouse cursor at the designated drag point.
Having to designate drag points for each curve is one of the inelegant features of this solution.

#### Update

Here is a version that doesn't require designating drag points in advance. Any point of a curve can serve as a drag point.

```
With[{span = 10., δ = .1},
  Framed @
    DynamicModule[
        {mXY, action, f1DragPt, f2DragPt, xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax, p1, p2},
      {xmin, xmax} = {ymin, ymax} = span {-1., 1.}/2.;
      p1 = p2 = {0., 0.};
      EventHandler[
        Dynamic @
          Plot[
            {f1[t - p1[[1]]] + p1[[2]], f2[t - p2[[1]]] + p2[[2]]}, 
            {t, xmin, xmax}, 
            AspectRatio -> Automatic, 
            PlotRange -> {{xmin, xmax}, {ymin, ymax}},
            GridLines ->
              {Floor /@ Range[xmin, xmax], Floor /@ Range[ymin, ymax]}],
        {"MouseDown" :>
          (mXY = MousePosition["Graphics"];
           Which[
             Abs[f1[mXY[[1]] - p1[[1]]] + p1[[2]] - mXY[[2]]] < δ, 
               f1DragPt = mXY - p1; action = "moveF1",
             Abs[f2[mXY[[1]] - p2[[1]]] + p2[[2]] - mXY[[2]]] < δ,
               f2DragPt = mXY - p2; action = "moveF2",
             True, action = "pan"])},
        {"MouseDragged" :>
          Module[{xy, dx, dy},
            xy = MousePosition["Graphics"];
            Switch[action,
              "pan", 
                 {dx, dy} = xy - mXY; xmin -= dx; xmax -= dx; ymin -= dy; ymax -= dy,
              "moveF1", p1 = xy - f1DragPt,
              "moveF2", p2 = xy - f2DragPt]]}]]]
```

Comment: Great solution.  I especially like the "delta" for recognizing closeness to the curves.  I have been working on a solution using a locator for the curve and event handler for panning as suggested. : )  I'll try and get mine running and post here, although I like your solution better.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution using Manipulate.

```
xmin = -5;
ymin = -5;
xmax = 5;
ymax = 5;
Manipulate[EventHandler[Dynamic@Show[
    Plot[{t - qt[[1]] + qt[[2]], (t - pt[[1]])^2 + pt[[2]]}, {t, xmin,
       xmax}],
    PlotRange -> {{xmin, xmax}, {ymin, ymax}},
    Axes -> True,
    GridLines -> {Floor /@ Range[xmin, xmax], 
      Floor /@ Range[ymin, ymax]},
    AspectRatio -> Automatic,
    Ticks -> False],
  If[Norm[MousePosition["Graphics"] - pt] > .3 && 
    Norm[MousePosition["Graphics"] - qt] > .3,
   {
    {"MouseDown" :> (mouseXY = MousePosition["Graphics"])},
    {"MouseDragged" :> Module[{dx, dy},
       {dx, dy} = (MousePosition["Graphics"] - mouseXY);
       xmin -= dx;
       xmax -= dx;
       ymin -= dy;
       ymax -= dy]}}]],
 {{pt, {-1, 1}}, Locator}, {{qt, {3, 3}}, Locator}]
```

[image]

If anyone sees any bad programming practice in my code or how it can be made better, let me know.  I would appreciate it.  Thank you!

Comment: Click close to the locators to move the curves.  Click further away to pan.

Comment: +1, but conceptual it's almost like replacing `Framed` in the [answer by m_goldberg](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/103058/18476) with `Manipulate`. Maybe it's time for you to advance to using `DynamicModule` instead of `Manipulate`. Or do you have any specific reason for using `Manipulate`? A straight implementation of this application in a pure `Manipulate` way might not even be possible though.

Comment: You're right.  I started off working on dynamicmodule for a few hours and couldn't get it to work so tried to fix it using manipulate but turns out I didn't change much.  Will work on leaning dynamicmodule.  Thanks!